# How much AWS Lambda Function consume computation resources for executing jobs ?

Tags: aws-lambda

I am not finding too much information about AWS lambda and at the same time I am really excited about it. Recently, there was a published paper called Serverless computation with Openlambda that had preposed a prototype for Lambda function.
AWS lambda is a block art and I wanna know more about it but I am not sure if the Amazon will be published more technical details about it.

So, what I wish to know is that, how Lambda do with computation resources. Particularly, when lambda scale up or down, what kind of instance will be hired, Network usages, and CPU usage.

Amazon offers something called CloudWatch that logs all sort of things about the code state and visualizes it for the use in a GUI. However, I am not sure if the log file will give some information about computation resources.

I am looking forward to see some answers.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you are asking, AWS has lots on information and documentation on AWS Lambda. Checking the [Getting Started Guide](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/getting-started/) provides all links to the information you need.

Regarding the resources there is a document called [How it works](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction.html). You don't hire anything, you just pay for the execution time. They will spin up a container for you.
They don't tell much details about the network and CPU, they just note it scales up with the memory as noted under [Flexible Resource Model](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/details/) or in the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/). If you search for [logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation-product&searchQuery=logging&x=0&y=0&this_doc_product=AWS+Lambda&this_doc_guide=Developer+Guide&doc_locale=en_us#facet_doc_product=AWS%20Lambda) within the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/) you will easily find out how to log to Cloudwatch using your favorite language.

Why don't you follow the [Getting Started Guide](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/getting-started/) and find the answers you are looking for on your way?

Comment: from your answer Quote "They don't tell much details about the network and CPU", and that's what I meant about not much information.